# RuntimeError: tensors must be 2-D

Tags: python, pytorch

I was running a simple MLP network with customized learning algorithms. It worked fine on the training set, but I got this error when I entered additional code to check the test accuracy. How can I fix it?

## Test Accuracy code

```
epochs = 1
for epcoh in range(epochs):
    model_bp.eval()
    model_fa.eval()
    test_loss_bp = 0
    correct_bp = 0
    test_loss_fa = 0
    correct_fa = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for idx_batch, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(test_loader):
            
            output_bp = model_bp(inputs)
            output_fa = model_fa(inputs)
            # sum up batch loss
            test_loss_bp += loss_crossentropy(output_bp, targets).item()
            test_loss_bp += loss_crossentropy(output_fa, targets).item()
            # get the index of the max log-probability
            ## predict_bp = outputs_bp.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True) 
            predict_bp = torch.max(output_bp.data,1)[1]
            correct_bp += predict_bp.eq(targets.view_as(predict_bp)).sum().item()

            predict_fa = torch.max(output_fa.data,1)[1]
            correct_fa += predict_fa.eq(targets.view_as(predict_fa)).sum().item()

    print('Test set: BP Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.4f}%)\n'.format(test_loss_bp, correct_bp, len(test_loader.dataset),
            100. * correct_bp / len(test_loader.dataset)))
    print('Test set: FA Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.4f}%)\n'.format(test_loss_fa, correct_fa, len(test_loader.dataset),
            100. * correct_fa / len(test_loader.dataset)))
```

## Error

I'm curious about the meaning of 'RuntimeError: tensors must be 2-D'. We would appreciate it if you could tell us why it happened and where you made the mistake.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-9b8b6f683e59> in <module>
     16             #targets = targets.to(device)
     17 
---> 18             output_bp = model_bp(inputs)
     19             output_fa = model_fa(inputs)
     20             # sum up batch loss

~\anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

c:\Users\bclab\Desktop\feedback-alignment-pytorch-master\lib\linear.py in forward(self, inputs)
    102         """
    103         # first layer
--> 104         linear1 = F.relu(self.linear[0](inputs))
    105 
    106         linear2 = self.linear[1](linear1)

~\anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

c:\Users\bclab\Desktop\feedback-alignment-pytorch-master\lib\linear.py in forward(self, input)
     69     def forward(self, input):
     70         # See the autograd section for explanation of what happens here.
---> 71         return LinearFunction.apply(input, self.weight, self.bias)
     72 
     73 

c:\Users\bclab\Desktop\feedback-alignment-pytorch-master\lib\linear.py in forward(ctx, input, weight, bias)
     11     def forward(ctx, input, weight, bias=None):
     12         ctx.save_for_backward(input, weight, bias)
---> 13         output = input.mm(weight.t())
     14         if bias is not None:
     15             output += bias.unsqueeze(0).expand_as(output)

RuntimeError: tensors must be 2-D
```

This is my model. And fa_linear, linear : customize network

```
# load feedforward dfa model
model_fa = fa_linear.LinearFANetwork(in_features=784, num_layers=2, num_hidden_list=[1000, 10]).to(device)

# load reference linear model
model_bp = linear.LinearNetwork(in_features=784, num_layers=2, num_hidden_list=[1000, 10]).to(device)

# optimizers
optimizer_fa = torch.optim.SGD(model_fa.parameters(),
                            lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.001, nesterov=True)
optimizer_bp = torch.optim.SGD(model_bp.parameters(),
                            lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.001, nesterov=True)

loss_crossentropy = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# make log file
results_path = 'bp_vs_fa_'
logger_train = open(results_path + 'train_log2.txt', 'w')
```

## linear

```
from torch.autograd import Function
from torch import nn
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

# Inherit from Function
class LinearFunction(Function):
    # Note that both forward and backward are @staticmethods
    @staticmethod
    # bias is an optional argument
    def forward(ctx, input, weight, bias=None):
        ctx.save_for_backward(input, weight, bias)
        output = input.mm(weight.t())
        if bias is not None:
            output += bias.unsqueeze(0).expand_as(output)
        return output

    # This function has only a single output, so it gets only one gradient
    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        # This is a pattern that is very convenient - at the top of backward
        # unpack saved_tensors and initialize all gradients w.r.t. inputs to
        # None. Thanks to the fact               that additional trailing Nones are
        # ignored, the return statement is simple even when the function has
        # optional inputs.
        input, weight, bias = ctx.saved_variables
        grad_input = grad_weight = grad_bias = None
        # These needs_input_grad checks are optional and there only to
        # improve efficiency. If you want to make your code simpler, you can
        # skip them. Returning gradients for inputs that don't require it is
        # not an error.

        if ctx.needs_input_grad[0]:
            grad_input = grad_output.mm(weight)
        if ctx.needs_input_grad[1]:
            grad_weight = grad_output.t().mm(input)
        if bias is not None and ctx.needs_input_grad[2]:
            grad_bias = grad_output.sum(0).squeeze(0)

        return grad_input, grad_weight, grad_bias


class Linear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_features, output_features, bias=True):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.input_features = input_features
        self.output_features = output_features

        # nn.Parameter is a special kind of Variable, that will get
        # automatically registered as Module's parameter once it's assigned
        # as an attribute. Parameters and buffers need to be registered, or
        # they won't appear in .parameters() (doesn't apply to buffers), and
        # won't be converted when e.g. .cuda() is called. You can use
        # .register_buffer() to register buffers.
        # nn.Parameters can never be volatile and, different than Variables,
        # they require gradients by default.
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(output_features, input_features))
        if bias:
            self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(output_features))
        else:
            # You should always register all possible parameters, but the
            # optional ones can be None if you want.
            self.register_parameter('bias', None)

        # weight initialization
        torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform(self.weight)
        torch.nn.init.constant(self.bias, 1)

    def forward(self, input):
        # See the autograd section for explanation of what happens here.
        return LinearFunction.apply(input, self.weight, self.bias)


class LinearNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, num_layers, num_hidden_list):
        """
        :param in_features: dimension of input features (784 for MNIST)
        :param num_layers: number of layers for feed-forward net
        :param num_hidden_list: list of integers indicating hidden nodes of each layer
        """
        super(LinearNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.num_hidden_list = num_hidden_list

        # create list of linear layers
        # first hidden layer
        self.linear = [Linear(self.in_features, self.num_hidden_list[0])]
        # append additional hidden layers to list
        for idx in range(self.num_layers - 1):
            self.linear.append(Linear(self.num_hidden_list[idx], self.num_hidden_list[idx+1]))

        # create ModuleList to make list of layers work
        self.linear = nn.ModuleList(self.linear)


    def forward(self, inputs):
        """
        forward pass, which is same for conventional feed-forward net
        :param inputs: inputs with shape [batch_size, in_features]
        :return: logit outputs from the network
        """
        # first layer
        linear1 = F.relu(self.linear[0](inputs))

        linear2 = self.linear[1](linear1)

        return linear2
```

## fa_linear

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import autograd
from torch.autograd import Variable


class LinearFANetwork(nn.Module):
    """
    Linear feed-forward networks with feedback alignment learning
    Does NOT perform non-linear activation after each layer
    """
    def __init__(self, in_features, num_layers, num_hidden_list):
        """
        :param in_features: dimension of input features (784 for MNIST)
        :param num_layers: number of layers for feed-forward net
        :param num_hidden_list: list of integers indicating hidden nodes of each layer
        """
        super(LinearFANetwork, self).__init__()
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.num_hidden_list = num_hidden_list

        # create list of linear layers
        # first hidden layer
        self.linear = [LinearFAModule(self.in_features, self.num_hidden_list[0])]
        # append additional hidden layers to list
        for idx in range(self.num_layers - 1):
            self.linear.append(LinearFAModule(self.num_hidden_list[idx], self.num_hidden_list[idx+1]))

        # create ModuleList to make list of layers work
        self.linear = nn.ModuleList(self.linear)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        """
        forward pass, which is same for conventional feed-forward net
        :param inputs: inputs with shape [batch_size, in_features]
        :return: logit outputs from the network
        """

        # first layer
        linear1 = self.linear[0](inputs)

        # second layer
        linear2 = self.linear[1](linear1)

        return linear2


class LinearFAFunction(autograd.Function):

    @staticmethod
    # same as reference linear function, but with additional fa tensor for backward
    def forward(context, input, weight, weight_fa, bias=None):
        context.save_for_backward(input, weight, weight_fa, bias)
        output = input.mm(weight.t())
        if bias is not None:
            output += bias.unsqueeze(0).expand_as(output)
        return output

    @staticmethod
    def backward(context, grad_output):
        input, weight, weight_fa, bias = context.saved_variables
        grad_input = grad_weight = grad_weight_fa = grad_bias = None

        if context.needs_input_grad[0]:
            # all of the logic of FA resides in this one line
            # calculate the gradient of input with fixed fa tensor, rather than the "correct" model weight
            grad_input = grad_output.mm(weight_fa)
        if context.needs_input_grad[1]:
            # grad for weight with FA'ed grad_output from downstream layer
            # it is same with original linear function
            grad_weight = grad_output.t().mm(input)
        if bias is not None and context.needs_input_grad[3]:
            grad_bias = grad_output.sum(0).squeeze(0)

        return grad_input, grad_weight, grad_weight_fa, grad_bias


class LinearFAModule(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_features, output_features, bias=True):
        super(LinearFAModule, self).__init__()
        self.input_features = input_features
        self.output_features = output_features

        # weight and bias for forward pass
        # weight has transposed form; more efficient (so i heard) (transposed at forward pass)
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(output_features, input_features))
        if bias:
            self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(output_features))
        else:
            self.register_parameter('bias', None)

        # fixed random weight and bias for FA backward pass
        # does not need gradient
        self.weight_fa = nn.Parameter(Variable(torch.FloatTensor(output_features, input_features), requires_grad=False))

        # weight initialization
        torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform(self.weight)
        torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform(self.weight_fa)
        torch.nn.init.constant(self.bias, 1)

    def forward(self, input):
        return LinearFAFunction.apply(input, self.weight, self.weight_fa, self.bias)
```

Comment: can you do `print(input.shape)` before `output_bp = model_bp(inputs)`

Comment: The result of `print(input.shape)` is `torch.Size([10000, 1, 28, 28])` . I put 'test batch size' as 10000, and 'train batch size' as 32.

Comment: can you paste your `model ` class

Comment: I modified it by adding a model  to my post. Please check. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to flatten your input before passing it to your model. Something like this:

```py
# ...

# from [batch_size, 1, 28, 28] <- 4-D
# to   [batch_size, 1x28x28]   <- 2-D, as expected
flat_inputs = torch.flatten(inputs)

output_bp = model_bp(flat_inputs)
output_fa = model_fa(flat_inputs)

# ...
```

Comment: Oh, Thank's a lot! Based on your comments, I added `flat_inputs = torch.flatten(inputs, start_dim = 1)` to the code and it worked! Thank you so much.